# How to sort info from a text file into an array by type in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, text-files

I am trying to write a method that will read a text file that looks like this:

```
N 1000.0 NY 
R 2000.0 CA 0.09 
R 500.0 GA 0.07 
N 2000.0 WY 
O 3000.0 Japan 0.11 20.0 
N 555.50 CA 
O 3300.0 Ecuador 0.03 30.0 
R 600.0 NC 0.06
```

The starting letters are the different types of orders. Each type of order has different parameters. I want the method to read the orders from the text file in a format like this:
Type Price Location [TaxRate] [Tariff]. My point of confusion is how to sort the data into the array by type.

```
public static ArrayList<Order> readOrders (String fileName)
{

    File file = new File (fileName);

    scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, file not found: " + file.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Order[] order = new Order[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    String data = scan.nextLine(); // you need to use nextLine to read a whole line
    String[] val = data.split(" ");
    String type = val[0]; // Since its a String
    double price = Double.parseDouble(val[1]);
    String location = val[2];  // Since its a String
    double taxRate = 0.0; // Default values
    double tariff = 0.0; // Default values
    try { // Incase they are not present - error handling
    taxRate = Double.parseDouble(val[3]);
    tariff = Double.parseDouble(val[4]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
}
    ArrayList <Order> orders =new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(order));
    return orders;
```

I cannot get it to work with my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Order> orders2 = readOrders("orders.txt"); 

    for( Order o2 : orders2) 
    { 
        System.out.println( o2.printOrder("Long")); 
    } 

    for( Order o2 : orders2) 
    { 
        System.out.println(o2.printOrder("Short")); 
    } 

}
```

This is my error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method printOrder(String) is undefined for the type Order
    The method printOrder(String) is undefined for the type Order

    at prob1.OrderTester.main(OrderTester.java:19)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the Order class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer I was looking for. Here it is:

```
public static ArrayList<Order> readOrders (String fileName)
    {
        File file = new File (fileName);
        ArrayList<Order> o = new ArrayList<Order>();

        scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error, file not found: " + file.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String fl = scan.next();

            if (fl.equals("N"))
            {
                NonProfitOrder n = new NonProfitOrder(scan.nextDouble(), scan.next());
                o.add(n);
            }
            else if (fl.equals("R"))
            {
                RegularOrder r = new RegularOrder (scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextDouble());
                o.add(r);
            }
            else
            {
                OverseasOrder oo = new OverseasOrder(scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble());
                o.add(oo);
            }

        }
        return o;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. it is a compilation error. The class Order doesn't include the method you are calling. E.g.

```
    printOrder("Long")
```

Check the class Order. Here you have not provided it

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned you got a compilation error. Your Order class need to have a printOrder(String) method.

You should also check your readOrders method.
It seems to always return empty Orders because you create the order array with

`Order[] order = new Order[8];`

But NEVER assign something with something like:

`order[i] = new Order(type, price, location, etc ...);`

The catch block seems also wrong

`} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {`

you need to close it!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for sorting an array list by type is:

If it's not already, make `Order` implement `Comparable` and override `compareTo(Order o)` to return the following, assuming there is a `String type` field and it has an accessor method `getType()`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Order o) {
    return type.compareTo(o.getType());
}
```

Then simply call `Arrays.sort(orders)` once you've scanned the file.

Or use a `Comparator`.

Having said that, here's a short list of some of the *wrongest* things in your code:

(1) You haven't posted the source for the `Order` class, which is the main class with regards to the question you've asked. Makes it hard to give a more specific answer.

(2) The `readOrders()` function you've posted either is incomplete or (even if you add the couple of missing curly braces, and close the `for` loop) returns a list containing 8 null references. You need to instantiate the `Order` objects.

(3) Why use an array `Order[]` instead of just using the list with `ArrayList.add()`?

(4) Any time the `Scanner` fails to load the file, it will throw a `NullPointerException` on the first line after the `catch` block.

(5) Checking if your array has ended by catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()` is bad practice for a multitude of reasons. Google it if you don't believe me.

(6) You get a compilation error because the `Order.printOrder(String)` is not defined. Define it, or better yet override `Order.toString()`.

Consider rewriting your code to address these issues. There's likely more, these are just the things that jump out at first glance.